# How to make trigger function respond to certain collider pairs and not others?

Tags: unity, physics, collider

I assigned two colliders to one GameObject.
Both are different sizes. I am doing operations with Trigger messages.

[image: Diagram showing colliders that should interact]

I want this Trigger function to work for only colliders 1 and 3, but not collider 2.

Comment: This looks like a problem you can solve with [collision layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) to filter which colliders generate collision/trigger messages. How have you tried applying this to your situation so far?

Comment: [I have answered the same question in this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208554/how-to-make-the-player-pass-through-only-certain-objects-but-not-others/208562#208562)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the number 1 collider to the child gameobject and set it with the collison layer and I solved my problem.

Comment: Can you explain your solution in more detail, so that it can help future readers who do not have as clear an understanding of the system as you do now?