# How to make the player pass through only certain objects, but not others?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, collider

Experimenting with my 1st Unity project. It's about a top down swimmer. By toggling the swimmer's collider, he can swim under boats:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) swimmerCircleCollider.enabled = !swimmerCircleCollider.enabled;
```

At the same time I don't want him to be able to swim under the wharf, which is like an uncrossable barrier/border/wall or simply the end of playable area. How can I achieve that?

Is the idea of disabling the collider wrong in the first place? If so, please provide some guidelines for a better solution.

Comment: Have you looked into [physics layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can go to **Edit**->**Project Setting**->**Physics** or **Physics 2D**->**Layer Collision Matrix**. To change what you want your player pass through or not.
- To change it via code like what you wanted, I have a solution here. Ex: your Player's Layer position is 6 & your Enemy is 7.

[image]

```
private bool isSwimmingUnderWater = false;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        isSwimmingUnderWater = !isSwimmingUnderWater;
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(6, 7, isSwimmingUnderWater); //it will set the val of the Layer Collision of the Player and Enemy whether true or false
    }
}
```

I have tested it with my game and it works.

Comment: The *'Order in Layer'* under *'Sprite Renderer'* is the order inside the assigned *'Builtin Layer'* or *'User Layer'*?

Comment: It's working. Please, change `flag` to a property like `private bool isSwimmingUnderWater = false;` and put the `If` statement inside the `void Update() {}` method, to make things clearer, so I can mark your answer as solved. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I have changed my answer and sorry for my delayed response. Because of some problems with my laptop, now i having to code via my phone...

Comment: `isFreediving` would be even better than `isSwimmingUnderWater`, but nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a barrier you also could add a child object which gets activated and has an appropriate box collider.

But the Physics2D solution by **Tien Hung** is way more elegant!